# Xpath and Oracle XMLTABLE

Tags: oracle, xpath, oracle12c

I have a CLOB containing an XML.

```
<attrs>
    <attr name="1">
        <string>stringvalue</string>
    </attr>
    <attr name="2">
        <integer>1</integer>
    </attr>
    <attr name="3">
        <integer>2</integer>
    </attr>
    <attr name="4">
        <boolean>false</boolean>
    </attr>
</attrs>
```

How can I get **only** boolean attributs and the **name** attribute ?

```
XMLTABLE('/attrs/attr/boolean'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(CLOB)
    COLUMNS ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR2(50) PATH '???',
            ATTRIBUTEVALUE VARCHAR2(5) PATH '.'
) X
```

This way, I only have the value, how can I also get the parent @name ?
I can use '/attrs/attr' but I don't know how to get only the boolean (maybe I need to filter after ?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk back up the tree in  the column path with:

```
'./../@name'
```

so that gives:

```
XMLTABLE('/attrs/attr/boolean'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(CLOB)
    COLUMNS ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR2(50) PATH './../@name',
            ATTRIBUTEVALUE VARCHAR2(5) PATH '.'
) X
```

which with your data gets:

```
ATTRIBUTENAME ATTRIBUTEVALUE
------------- --------------
4             false
```

You could also apply a child-node filter in the main XPath with:

```
'/attrs/attr[boolean]'
```

and then get that `attr` node's name and its child `boolean` node, giving:

```
XMLTABLE('/attrs/attr[boolean]'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(your_CLOB)
    COLUMNS ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR2(50) PATH '@name',
            ATTRIBUTEVALUE VARCHAR2(5) PATH 'boolean'
) X
```

which gets the same result.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e7e2dd816ac14350496600d7bc353ac7)

Comment: Thank you so much, that's so clear to me now!